# pyparsing get all ignored comments text

Tags: python, pyparsing

Is there a way to of getting everything that was ignored using `ignore` in pyparsing?

For example I have:

```
import pyparsing as p

comment_till_end_of_line = ('--' + p.restOfLine)
sql_stmt.ignore(comment_till_end_of_line)
```

Then doing

```
res = sql_stmt.parseString("-- xyz\n--cpad")
```

Can I somehow do:

```
for x in res.<<someghihing>>:
    print(x)
```

to get

```
-- xyz
--cpad
```

I tried assigning a result name:

```
comment_till_end_of_line = ('--' + p.restOfLine).setResultsName('ignored')
sql_stmt.ignore(comment_till_end_of_line)  # Ignore comments


for x in res.ignored:
    print(x)
```

But that printed nothing.

Comment: See if this question/answer are helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66282969/need-to-keep-comments-in-pyparsing-grammar